# Data driven game with phaser 3

Tags: json, phaser-framework

well i'm working on an e-learning platform for kids that contain courses and each course contain lessons and some games
games will be programmed in phaser 3
so the admin in the dashboard will have a form to add new course (add  the lesson which is a video and also a link to the phaser game since the admin is not a developer so i wanted to transform my phaser game to a link or something like that  )
my question is how to get a game set up to use data from json objects from a URL [sort of Data-driven game ]
ps: to develop this platform i'm using spring boot and angular

Comment: "use data from json objects" - what sort of data? The current answer is if the assets are stored in JSON, but are the questions/answers the data you want to pull in?

Answer (score 1):

Until you actually instantiate a Phaser game as e.g. `const game = Phaser.Game(myconfig)`, you can do any number of things to load the required data asynchronously.  So the part about getting data is resolved that way.

The question of how to actually use the data is a more broad question.  I would consider thinking about the asset loading and then instantiation *together*, and set up predefined factory functions to consume the same data the `Loader` functions will take.

You can trivially load assets from json data with the `pack` method in the Loader plugin, see [here](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin-pack).

Then, you need to implement something that will act upon those assets once they are loaded, depending on the data:

```json
{
...

"sceneSprites":{
    "oneSprite":{'
        "textureKey": "myAssetLoaded",
        "x":32,
        "y":42,
        "tint": 0xff0000
        (etc)
    }
}
}
```

The keys that you define in the "pack" part of the json will be in the TextureManager, and you just match that key in the object data.

Then you create a scene with a series of functions that iterate over the data you have and create objects based on the data:

```js
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    create(){
       for(const obj of spriteData){
           const spr=this.add.sprite(obj.x,obj.y,obj.texturKey)
           spr.setTint(obj.tint)
       }
    }
}
```

This is just a rough sketch of the things you would have to do.  In general you can create one phaser "game" that is built with enough helper factory functions ontop of what phaser provides, to consume the specific data you have in any of your given json files.

I am sure you could cover a lot of Phaser functionality this way, including tweens, shaders, and audio.